# Class for arXiv preprints

Tags: document-classes

I wondered whether there was a class designed specifically for arxiv preprints? Take a look at e.g. [this list of arxiv preprints](http://arxiv.org/list/hep-ph/recent). There isn't really a canonical choice at the moment. Many authors:

- Use a journal class supplied by a journal e.g. revtex. This can have drawbacks, as journal classes aren't necessarily designed to be read online. They may be two column or have other unusual spacing. Furthermore, you may not know which journal you paper will be submitted to or accepted by!
- Use a modified version of the report class. The drawbacks are that this wasn't designed with preprints in mind. The default page margins etc are too big and the title page cannot by default accept multiple authors with different email addresses and institutions.

I wondered if there was or are plans to develop a dedicated arxiv class. It would have spacing optimised for on-screen reading etc, have a flexible title page, useful macros for consistent formatting of references to tables and figures, a default bibtex style file that supported links to other arxiv documents, support subfigures and nicely formatted tables out the box.

Or is a customised report class really the best way to go?

Comment: I'm sure I'm not alone in finding that reading papers properly means printing them off. I suspect most people use a journal class as they hope to go from arXiv to a journal, so don't want to have to re-work everything. However, all of this is discussion: I'm not sure the above falls within the Q&A format here (beyond 'no, there is no dedicated class').

Comment: Think of the number of online reads vs on paper reads for the arxiv. I'd guess as at least 50 to 1. Most reading is online, for sure. Copy editors refigure the latex on submission, so that isn't a factor.

Comment: There's nothing like this that's ever begun development? It surprises me. There's packages for everything, but not this obvious thing?

Comment: Sure, most reading I do is online ('real' journals: I'm a chemist so there are no pre-prints) but the moment I want to _properly_ read a paper I always print it (and I always read the PDF versions not the HTML ones anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure it is obvious: what are the specific requirements for arXiv not covered elsewhere (and that would not cause issues with actually submitting a paper: most people won't want to re-write everything).

Comment: Maybe it's field dependent. I'm sure there are fields where most reading is online arxiv. My experience is genuinely that jounals have copy editors that put the paper in their format. That's why many people at present use customised report classes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37512/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-innisfree).